# Explode/Implode Text on Reveal/Hide(and not expand but recompose page back to normal)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found several different pieces of code, but I do not know how to put them altogether so they work together.  Please help.

Reveals/Hides part of text:
[Show more show less with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566137/show-more-show-less-with-jquery)

Explode/Implode Text: [Literally explode text apart to random places with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656353/literally-explode-text-apart-to-random-places-with-jquery)

How do I combine the 2?  I want to start off with partial of the paragraph text hidden, and when someone clicks "Read More" it will reveal(open up) a "spot" where Implode text will come together and reveal the rest of the paragraph with text, images, or whatever.  For when someone clicks on "Collapse Text", the partial of the paragraph that was revealed will explodes and the "spot" will close up and restore the page back to the original way it was.

Answer (score 0):

The space you want Opened up and swept away should occur automatically as default DOM Manipulation "Cleans up after itself" in a way. This code should do exactly what you need :)

**EDIT** I've changed this code to work for any jquery/jquery UI. Remove the display none from the text and use this code.

```
 <a href="javascript:;" id="openLink">Read More</a>
 <p id="text" >lorem ipsum dolowhatever this is</p>

 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 $("#text").hide();
 $("#openLink").toggle(function () {
   $("#text").show('explode', {}, 600);
   $("#openLink").text("Read Less");
   }, function () {
   $("#text").hide('explode', {}, 600);
   $("#openLink").text("Read More");
  });
});
</script>
```

[Reference](http://www.devcurry.com/2010/01/explode-and-implode-element-using.html)  -->[Demo](http://jsbin.com/uyena3) -->[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bCz4T/12/)

Comment: I had to make a couple edits sorry, I'm running coffeeless today :[

Comment: Thank you, but I'm trying to get your code to work however when I click on Read More, it just changes to Read Less, but no explosion/implosion.  Is there something else in the HTML that is not in the JSFiddle that I need to add?

Comment: In the jsfiddle, I did have to have EDIT[JQuery 1.8.18] and Jquery UI 1.8.3] added. Is it working on that? (third link)

Comment: Yes it is working in JSFiddle, but I made a fresh new HTML and Javascript page with your code, and I don't see it working for some reason.

Comment: Gotcha, please be sure to use JQuery 1.8.18 and Jquery UI 1.8.3. For some reason, those are what allowed this valid JQuery to run.

Comment: Actually, just see new JSFIddle, I've changed it

Comment: I still can't put it in an actual working document away from Fiddle.  Do you have email? I can send you what I got, see what's wrong?

Comment: This works great on JSFiddle, but on anything else, it doesn't work no matter what I do. Thanks.  If anyone else has another suggestion, please post.

Comment: The <script type="text/javascript"> gives me a completely blank screen.

Comment: There we go, in the top left of the screen, you'll notice in your fiddle you're using "no library". http://jsfiddle.net/GxpX8/1/ I've updated your jsfiddle by removing the jquery calls in the top and using the proper libraries up there

Comment: Can you please provide the correct script tags in the HTMl of your JS Fiddle instead of check marking Jquery UI 1.8.3.  Link every tag I need in the head tag.  This is where my problem is.

Comment: gotcha, two seconds I'll see if I can work it out for you on there

Comment: Sorry to trouble you further, but could you please email me the HTML, js files? gibberkay@yahoo.com  No matter what I do, I can't make .html/.js files out your code even though it works in JS fiddle. I'm doing something wrong.